# `x2gostartagent` `command` argument specification

Tags: xorg, remote-access

Regarding `x2go`, a remote X system, that I am using with an ubuntu client and a headless ubuntu server with the `ubuntu-desktop` is the following question.

I gather that on the server I have to issue a command such as:

> x2gostartagent geometry link_quality nx_pack_meth
>   cache_type+dpi kblayout kbtype setkbd session_type command

My actual command was:

> x2gostartagent 800x600 adsl 16m-jpeg unix-kde-depth_24 us pc105/us 1 D
>   pwd

The unix-kde-depth_24 argument is described in the man page as the "most common" but no alternatives are offered so I'm not sure what to use other than this value.

I am not sure about the `pwd` command at the end of this set of arguments so I did an arbitrary linux command `pwd`. This command argument is described as

> only used to create the session ID for this new X2go session

and that's not much help.  How does one correctly specify the "command" argument?  (BTW: The remote session works.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not issue the `x2gostartagent` command on the server.  Issuing it will result in strange behaviour.  The client can issue it but since you can use the client that is already installed in ubuntu, there is no need to do it explicitly or manually.